# hard link to share files in git osx

Tags: macos, hardlink

I am trying to share a config file `~/.spacemacs` in a `git` repository `~/repo/config/spacemacs`.

Since I am on osx, I installed [hardlink](https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink) and used it like :

```
➜  ~  hln ~/.spacemacs ~/repo/config/spacemacs
```

The end goal is to be able to edit the file in both place.

A simple link seems to work when editing it simply.

```
ln ~/.spacemacs ~/repo/config/spacemacs
```

But then a `git stash` will only work on the repository.
But to commit it to git. What am I missing ?

Comment: Did you try to put the "original" file in the git repository and to do a symbolic link out (`ln -s git/path/file other/place/file `)?

Comment: @Hastur I did the reverse. It works now, although I thought I tried the simple link first. Thanks.

Comment: Ops now I see you answer... I write in the middle. There is not a _simple_ link in Linux/BSD. There are hard and symbolic.With [different way to act](http://askubuntu.com/a/43599/196535). As often there are many ways to solve a single task. Ps> BTW I think you can post question and answer at the same time...

Comment: @Hastur Yes of course. I am deleting my answer. Seems like editing works but `git stash`  breaks it.

Comment: Let me know (with a comment) if it works what proposed above... the _original_ file in the git repository and the link outside. With a _simple_ `ln -s ` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most *simple* way is to put the *original* file in the git repository and to do a symbolic (or hard) link from outside.

```
ln -s git/path/file other/place/file
```

One of the many sources about the differences between hard and symbolic links <sup>[[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/43599/196535)]</sup>.